# Сделать текст безопасным для сайта

Tags: php

Собственно, пишу для себя форум и возник вопрос. 
Какие лучше использовать функции работы с текстом, что бы сделать `html` теги и конструкции типа "`<b onclick="alert('сайт хакнут')">dsfsdfsdf</b>`". Хотел бы узнать чем лучше пользоваться stripslashes, addslashes,htmlspecialchars

Comment: чтобы **избежать** такого, вам нужна функция `striptags()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем в отдельный случаях, обычно и лучше htmlspecialchars, либо слешами. Если хочешь писать мощный форум, пиши в скайп(Manitikyl), может чем помогу, сам писал несколько форумов, знаком немного с архитектурой/структурой